# prevent redirect to php file after form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

After researching this for too many hours I finally decided to post the question myself, as what is working for others, doesn't seem to work for me. Please keep in mind that I am fairly new to ajax and jquery, but as I am on a deadline with my current project I wont have time to go through it all.

I have the following html form:

```
<div class="form">
    <form id="savePlacemarkForm" method="post" action="createPlacemark.php">
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="placemarkName" name="placemarkName" placeholder="Name:"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="placemarkAddress" name="placemarkAddress" placeholder="Adress:"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="placemarkTag" name="placemarkTag" placeholder="Tags:"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <textarea id="placemarkDescription" name="placemarkDescription" placeholder="Description" rows="1" cols="1"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input id="latitude" type="text" name="latitude"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input id="longtitude" type="text" name="longtitude"/>
        </div>
        <button class="md-close" id="savePlacemark" onclick="createPlacemark();"/>Save</button>
    </form>
    <button class="md-close">Cancel</button>
    <script src="my_script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</div>
```

As you see I have the action set to createPlacemark.php which takes input from these fields and saves it to my DB, which works fine!! However since this should work without redirecting or resubmitting the page, meaning ajax! I include my_script.js which looks like this:

```
$("#savePlacemark").click( function() {
    $.post( $("#savePlacemarkForm").attr("action"), 
        $("#savePlacemarkForm :input").serializeArray();                     
    });
    clearInput();
});

$("#savePlacemarkForm").submit( function() {
    return false;   
});

function clearInput() {
    $("#savePlacemarkForm :input").each( function() {
        $(this).val('');
    });
}
```

As you see it does the post for me, which works, but for some reason the return false; doesnt seem to work for me, as I am continuously redirected to the before mentioned php file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! thx!

Comment: Just a short aside, there's no need for the `each()` function inside your `clearInput()` function. It is sufficient to write: `$('#savePlacemarkForm :input').val('');`

Comment: Try `return json_encode($_POST)` at the beginning of processing AJAX request, then watch NETWORK tab in Chrome Developer Tools. It will show what your script received in request, that will help you indentify the problem.

Comment: sorry, where exactly do I write the json_encode($_POST)?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. The `.submit()` function actually triggers a submit for the form. Take this out of the script since you don't need it when you've already posted the values with `$.post`.

```
$("#savePlacemark").click( function() {
 $.post( $("#savePlacemarkForm").attr("action"), 
         $("#savePlacemarkForm :input").serializeArray();                    
  });
  clearInput();
});

function clearInput() {
    $("#savePlacemarkForm :input").each( function() {
       $(this).val('');
    });
}
```

Comment: same problem. When you remove this code you remove the return false, which (for what I can see in other places) is what should prevent the redirect.

Comment: What does `createPlacemark()` do? Since there's nothing on the page that can actually trigger a redirect now.

Comment: createPlacemark.php takes all the values from the form and saves them in my database, which works correctly! So everything exept that it triggers the redirect works.

Comment: I mean the javascript function. You have an `onclick="createPlacemark();"` aswell as a click event on that button.

Comment: Oh, yes, createPlacemark does an update to the UI, basically it places a placemark on my map in the position you are looking at... However, it doesnt change anything wheather it is there or not...

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<button onclick="return createPlacemark();">Save</button>
```

it may help you.